# Installing systemd-resolved kills dns lookup

Tags: debian, hostname, host-name-resolution

**Update**
After uninstalling and re-installing `systemd-resolved`, the issue seems to have righted itself. I do not understand why, but I did notice that the `/etc/resolv.conf` does not get modified after installing `systemd-resolved` for the second time, where it was modified the first time I installed the package.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to follow the Home-Assistant supervised installer instructions [here](https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer) on my Orange Pi Zero running Debian. This was set up from a netboot image. After installing the `systemd-resolved` package, the system can no longer look up website addresses. Uninstalling the package resolves the issue. This is the error:

`Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'`

**Observations:**

This did not happen when using an Armbian image for my unit, but Home-Assistant does not support Armbian, so I am trying with Debian instead.

I can't ping web addresses (or .locals on my network), but I can ping IP addresses.

**Working vs expected working:**

Expected (working before installing `systemd-resolved`)

```
jodie@orangePiZero:~$ wget -O homeassistant-supervised.deb https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/latest/download/homeassistant-supervised.deb
--2023-11-22 00:00:49--  https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/latest/download/homeassistant-supervised.deb
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 20.87.245.0
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|20.87.245.0|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/download/1.5.0/homeassistant-supervised.deb [following]
--2023-11-22 00:00:50--  https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/download/1.5.0/homeassistant-supervised.deb
Reusing existing connection to github.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/183216119/905cc380-f350-4a95-ac33-a2749b7858fa?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20231121%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231121T220050Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=21a10eb8987bbe62d3a2826be9ba66ed9476dbbe6015990ad0fb53b46db6224f&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=183216119&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dhomeassistant-supervised.deb&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream [following]
--2023-11-22 00:00:50--  https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/183216119/905cc380-f350-4a95-ac33-a2749b7858fa?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20231121%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231121T220050Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=21a10eb8987bbe62d3a2826be9ba66ed9476dbbe6015990ad0fb53b46db6224f&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=183216119&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dhomeassistant-supervised.deb&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream
Resolving objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.110.133, ...
Connecting to objects.githubusercontent.com (objects.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.108.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6504 (6.4K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘homeassistant-supervised.deb’

homeassistant-supervised.d 100%[=======================================>]   6.35K  --.-KB/s    in 0.002s

2023-11-22 00:00:51 (2.50 MB/s) - ‘homeassistant-supervised.deb’ saved [6504/6504]
```

Not working:

```
jodie@orangePiZero:~$ wget -O homeassistant-supervised.deb https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/latest/download/homeassistant-supervised.deb
--2023-11-22 17:11:35--  https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/releases/latest/download/homeassistant-supervised.deb
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
```

**Network setup:**

I have a tp-link home router set with a DHCP address reservation for this device's MAC address. It's on the same subnet as my other devices and does not specify a different DNS server. I can still ssh into the device (which is how I'm primarily setting it up)

**Question:**

Is there a configuration I need to set for DNS to work with `systemd-resolved`?

**Requested info:**

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` before installing `systemd-resolved`:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 0.0.0.0
```

Contents after first install:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

Contents after uninstall and re-install:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 0.0.0.0
```

Contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` before installing `systemd-resolved`:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files systemd
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Contents after first install of `systemd-resolved`:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files systemd
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Contents after uninstall and re-install of `systemd-resolved`

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files systemd
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**Other info**

This is the result of running `resolvectl status`:

```
jodie@orangePiZero:~$ resolvectl status
Failed to get global data: Connection timed out
```

This is the output of `systemctl status systemd-resolved`:

```
jodie@orangePiZero:~$ systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-11-21 23:09:21 SAST; 24min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 577 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1075)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 847ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─577 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

Comment: "_I can't ping web addresses_" - the `ping` command doesn't understand web addresses; it operates on IP addresses and host names. Please provide examples in your question of something that works and something that you think should but doesn't work. Include any error messages or other information

Comment: @ChrisDavies sorry to only reply now. I had a power failure today.

Comment: Not a problem. I'll wait until you've had time to address all the requests

Comment: I was under the impression I had now addressed everything. There's the contents of the .conf files and the Network Setup (Reserved DHCP).

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed your "something that works and something that you think should but doesn't work."

Comment: Okay, so something really weird has happened: I uninstalled systemd-resolved to get a working DNS lookup. That worked. Then when I re-installed it, DNS lookup continued to work. I notice that `/etc/resolv.conf` matches the initial value.

Comment: Well after an hour the issue is back. In the meantime I was able to install Home Assistant in docker, but after a while the unit cannot resolve any web addresses.
`/etc/resolv.conf` is now blank apart from a comment line `# Generated by NetworkManager`

Comment: Got same "random" error "Temporary failure in name resolution" after a regular system upgrade. Using systemd-resolved.x86_64 on fedora 253.12-1.fc38.
etc/resolve.conf had 127.0.0.53 and as a workaround, modifying the file to another address worked for few seconds only, because the file gets automatically replaced with 127.0.0.53.
Only systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service avoided the file to be replaced and I can work again. Maybe the resolution errors started to happen after midnight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that systemd-resolved somehow sets `network-manager`'s settings to be manual, yet keeps the correct IP address. To fix this, you can run `nmtui` (network manager terminal user interface) from the terminal and set your network settings back to automatic (dhcp).

After I installed Home Assistant Supervisor and it ran correctly, the settings became managed by the Home Assistant Supervisor.